# Aura/LWC: How to do not merge multiple apex calls and send them separately?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, callout, aura

If open network you can see calls like this:

```
/aura?r=14&aura.ApexAction.execute=3
```

where 3 (or 1, or 2, or any other number) is apex calls count has been sent together. And it causes errors because of "uncommitted work pending"

Is there a way to send apex call requests separately?

Actually such code works, but it's definitely not expected to do things like that.

```
Aura.$Services$.$AuraClientService$.prototype.$setXHRExclusivity$(true)
```

Full source is here:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/cfc6f05ff3758db06dbc1e45136a7247516a634f/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/AuraClientService.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept of batching apex calls together is called [boxcar'ing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_queue.htm?search_text=boxcar).

You can send/receive a long running apex call separately by using [setBackground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_background_actions.htm?search_text=boxcar)

```
// set up the server-action action
var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
// optionally set actions params
//action.setParams({ firstName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });
// set as a background action
action.setBackground();
```

Note: In LWC its currently not available. You can refer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263382/how-to-turn-boxcarring-off-for-lwc-imperative-apex-method-calls)

Answer (score 1):

Check [winter 2020](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_lc_predictable_apex_limits.htm) release notes from salesforce

**Hitting Apex Limits in Server-Side Actions Is More Predictable**

> Apex limits in Lightning components are now applied per action.
>   Previously, the Apex limits applied across all the actions batched
>   together (boxcar’ed) in a request (XHR). Where: This change applies to
>   Aura components and Lightning web components in Lightning Experience,
>   Salesforce Classic, Lightning communities, and all versions of the
>   Salesforce app.

so this issue that you are seeing will automatically go away after winter 2020 release.