# Simultaneous HTTP Callouts from Lightning Component with a single callback

Tags: lightning-aura-components, httprequest

I have a case where I have to call a 3rd party's API anywhere from 1 to 5 times, and I would like to have the page have a "loading" screen until they have all completed. Ideally, I would want these callouts to happen concurrently as opposed to consecutively. Where I am stumbling is that the number of requests needed is indeterminate until someone is accessing the record in question (as the number of requests is based on how many child records there are).

Is this something I can use promises for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the endpoint to the [CSP Trusted Sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=csp_trusted_sites.htm&type=5) list, you should be able to call the APIs concurrently. And yes, Promises could be used for this use case.

Note that browsers can choose how many open connections to maintain at once, so you might still not see truly concurrent access, and, of course, JavaScript is not multi-threaded, so each response will still be parsed one at a time, but aside from those caveats, it should work about as well as you'd expect.

If you use server-side (Apex) callouts, they may happen serially, because of the "boxcar effect" and the fact that Apex is single-threaded, so the calls will may occur serially and take longer to complete than if they can run concurrently.

Edit: Edited to specify that recent optimizations to the boxcar effect may not affect LWC as long as there are open connections in the browser. [This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/boxcaring-is-removed-from-lwc-components/293031#293031) goes in to more details.

Comment: The use of server-side callouts will not necessarily happen serially since boxcarring is not applied to every single LWC wire/imperative call. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/boxcaring-is-removed-from-lwc-components/293031#293031) for some info from Salesforce and some analysis and findings from myself.

Comment: @PhilW That's cool info. I've incorporated it into the answer.