# How to block the Lightning App Builder "Page Analysis" popup?

Tags: lightning-app-builder

This "Page Analysis" popup appears every time I open the lightning app builder, including on a production instance. If I close it and refresh the page, it pops up again. It is not a useful tool, and LWCs are fundamentally a slow technology, making optimization a losing battle, and the popup not useful. Is there a way to permanently hide it?

[image: Page Analysis]

Comment: I disagree that LWCs use/are slow technology - Aura is the slow tech, so unless you rolled your own LWCs for everything and used an LWR Build Your Own template you will be seeing Aura's poor performance in general. Obviously you can also write poorly performing LWCs and you can fail to orchestrate your Apex invocations which will also give your poor performance, but that is quite a different story. As to your specific question I don't have an answer but can say that this must either be new or you must have it specifically enabled on your org; I have not seen this appear unsolicited.

Comment: We have rolled our own LWCs for most things, was that a mistake? Most of our LWCs make 1-2 controller action calls to load data. On this page with the popup, 4 LWCs are called out. It says some components are "heavy" even though two of them only make one controller action call on load to fetch a few records.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not obvious - but, there's an ability to `Mute Tips` in the help drop down on the builder that will turn this off.

[image]

There is also an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000J8TySUAV/turn-off-autoload-for-lightning-page-analysis) about this behavior where I see the above option mentioned.

---

*Old Answer*

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear so. [Lightning Page Performance](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_performance.htm&type=5) outlines this:

> Performance Analysis for App Builder **automatically runs** when you build a page. **If your page performance is poor or moderate**, recommendations to improve performance **appear**.

The only way to not have it appear is to have *good* page performance. In terms of "improving it", it's worth pointing out the analysis only takes into account visible components on the page

> It assesses page performance based on all visible standard and custom components on the page. **Components in nondefault tabs and Accordion sections aren’t analyzed.**

Comment: There's something insidious about this platform - if an LWC makes a data request to Salesforce, if that request takes say, one second, it seems like _all_ LWCs on the page get blocked until the long poll request finishes. Is that how LWC data fetching works? Salesforce seems to think that a request that takes 1 second makes the component "heavy", even though it's Salesforce's data fetching <> Aura slowness (even for one record) that's the culprit. Am I doing something wrong, or is this fundamentally a flawed ecosystem?

Comment: In terms of many LWCs on the same page, this [question about boxcarring](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293025/boxcaring-is-removed-from-lwc-components) is worth a read - but, are you seeing actual performance issues in real-world usage or just going off this pop up on the page builder? I'll say the "heavy" note doesn't seem useful (or just flags certain criteria) as I've seen it flag a "heavy" component yet it's faster in the component performance breakdown than the other components on the page it doesn't list as heavy.