# Aura component: Mutiple $A.enqueueAction takes long time

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, fileupload, callback, promises

I'm testing a component where I upload a file, convert to base64 and split into several CHUNK Parts send each one to an apex method.

This component seems quite common online. Like:

- https://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/09/25/file-upload-lightning-component/

Bellow, is the method that performs my invocation to apex

```
uploadInChunk: function(component, file, fileContents, startPosition, endPosition, actualPart, totalParts) {

    var filePart= fileContents.substring(startPosition, endPosition);

    var action = component.get("c.uploadDocument");
    action.setParams({
       actualPart: String(actualPart),
       totalParts : String(totalParts),
       recordID : component.get('v.recordID'),
       part : filePart
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                startPosition = endPosition;
                endPosition = Math.min(fileContents.length, startPosition + this.CHUNK_SIZE);
                                    
                if (startPosition < endPosition) {
                    this.uploadInChunk(component, file, fileContents, startPosition,endPosition,(actualPart+1),totalParts);
                } else {
                    this.showToast(component,$A.get("$Label.c.uploading"), 'Info');
                }
         } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            this.showToast(component, $A.get("$Label.c.Fail"), 'Error');
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            this.showToast(component, Error, 'Error');
            var errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    component.set("v.showLoadingSpinner", false);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        }
    });
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

My issue is about the perfomance.

The apex method only invokes a future method so the transaction is fast, however the callback to javascript takes a few more seconds. When I have 30/40 parts it delays the whole process to some minutes.

I realized that the filePart, being a very large String, passing as an input is the most delaying cause. (Commenting that input turns the callbacks much more faster :P )

I found something about promises and I still try to perform the invocation outside the setCallback, since I really don't need the response. But I couldn't manage that.

Can you help me on that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn boxcarring OFF for LWC imperative apex method calls?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263382/how-to-turn-boxcarring-off-for-lwc-imperative-apex-method-calls)

Comment: @PhilW thanks but not really. I tried action.setBackground() before my $A.enqueueAction(action);.
It takes about 5 minutes for a 20MB upload (about 27 executions)
Another test I perform was (cacheable=true) but it was the same