# How to get record field value without click of a button in JS Controller?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Here, I wanted to submit value of Case Subject to the 'askk' function automatically on page load.

The question is - How to get Case Subject field value without click of a button in JS Controller.

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import askk from '@salesforce/apex/Q_Integration.askk';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import Subject_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';
import Status_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Status';
const fields = [Subject_FIELD, Status_FIELD];

export default class Q_AutoSubmit extends LightningElement {
    @track response = '';  
    @api recordId;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    caseRecord;

    connectedCallback() {
            const subjectFieldValue = getFieldValue(this.caseRecord.data, Subject_FIELD);
        //    const statusFieldValue = getFieldValue(this.caseRecord.data, Status_FIELD);

        alert(subjectFieldValue);//Problem: alerts undefined
        askk({question:subjectFieldValue})
            .then(result => {
                this.response = JSON.stringify(result) ;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                this.response = JSON.stringify(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire methods are not loaded with data until *after* `connectedCallback` returns (see [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/377193/2984) regarding wire timings). In your case, a wire handler is appropriate here:

```
export default class Q_AutoSubmit extends LightningElement {
  @track response = "";
  @api recordId;
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields }) handleCaseRecord(result) {
    if (result.data) {
      const subjectFieldValue = getFieldValue(result.data, Subject_FIELD);
      alert(subjectFieldValue); //Problem: alerts undefined
      askk({ question: subjectFieldValue })
        .then((result) => {
          this.response = JSON.stringify(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.response = JSON.stringify(error);
        });
    }
  }
}
```