# connectedCallback not working for wire

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, rest-api

I have an assignment I need to consume two APIs https://e2af7f77-77a7-4a41-b338-39d484c85745.mock.pstmn.io/categories (Get method)
https://e2af7f77-77a7-4a41-b338-39d484c85745.mock.pstmn.io/stocks (Get method)

One will return the categories the other an Stocks that is related to the Categories.

I am trying to use ApEX to make the API call and its returning the valus.
The problem is that is getting undefined on the JS side. ANd I can see that there are some rows in the json showing that the data was transfer to JS from APEX controller>

How can I get this data to show on the Template HTML?

````
import getRemainingBudget from '@salesforce/apex/StockExchangeController.getRemainingBudget';
import getCategories from '@salesforce/apex/StockExchangeController.getCategories';
import getStocks from '@salesforce/apex/StockExchangeController.getStocks';

export default class StockExchange extends LightningElement {

stockData = [];
hasData =false;
budgetValue;
error
counter = 0;

        handleIncrement() {
        this.counter++;
        }
        handleDecrement() {
        this.counter--;
        }

        @wire (getRemainingBudget)
        wiredBudget({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.budgetValue = data;
            console.log('Budget Data:', this.budgetValue);
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
        }

        @wire(getCategories)
        wiredCategories({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                this.categoriesData = data;
                console.log(data)
                this.categoriesData.forEach(category => {
                        console.log('Category ID:', category.Id);
                        console.log('Category Name:', category.Name);
                    });
                } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
                }
        }

        @wire(getStocks)
        wiredStocks({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                this.stocksData = data;
                console.log('Stocks: '+ data)
                console.log('Stocks object:', JSON.stringify(data));

                this.stocksData.forEach(stock => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(stock));
                    });
                } else if (error) {
                this.error = error;
                }
        }

        connectedCallback() {
                this.combineData();
        }
        
            combineData() {
                // Ensure both categories and stocks are loaded
                console.log('Stocks object:', JSON.stringify(this.stocksData));
                console.log('Categories object:', JSON.stringify(this.categoriesData));

                if (this.categoriesData && this.stocksData) {
                    let categoryMap = new Map();
                    this.categoriesData.forEach(cat => {
                        categoryMap.set(cat.Id, cat.Name);
                    });
        
                    this.stockData = this.stocksData.map((stock, index) => ({
                        Id: index + 1, // Adding an incremental Id
                        ...stock,
                        CategoryName: categoryMap.get(stock.Category)
                    }));
                    this.hasData = true;
                } else  {
                    
                    console.error('Error');
                }

                console.log('Test');
            }

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Wire methods are guaranteed to not have any data until after `connectedCallback` (see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/377190/2984)). Instead, call your method from the handlers:

```
@wire(getCategories)
    wiredCategories({ error, data }) {
            if (data) {
            this.categoriesData = data;
            console.log(data)
            this.categoriesData.forEach(category => {
                    console.log('Category ID:', category.Id);
                    console.log('Category Name:', category.Name);
                });
            } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            }
       this.combineData();
    }
    // same for the other method
```

And in combineData, wait until you have your data:

```
combineData() {
  if(!this.stocksData || !this.categoriesData) {
    return;
  }
  // rest of code
}
```

Comment: I did this change but didn't work.

` @wire(getCategories)
        wiredCategories({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                this.categoriesData = data;
                
        }
        @wire(getStocks)
        wiredStocks({ error, data }) {
                if (data) {
                this.stocksData = data;
               
                this.combineData();
                }
        }
`

Comment: `combineData() {
        // Ensure both categories and stocks are loaded
        console.log('Stocks object:', JSON.stringify(this.stocksData));
        console.log('Categories object:', JSON.stringify(this.categoriesData));
        if(!this.stocksData || !this.categoriesData) {
                return;
        }

        if (this.categoriesData && this.stocksData) {

}
`

Comment: Still shows empty.

Comment: Maybe would be better make the processing all in one Apex methos and them get the result from the apex?

Comment: @FábioNiglio Call combineData from *both* methods. You can't guarantee which will come first.